# React router DOM : Switch not working if child element isnt a route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm facing an issue im not able to comprehend. I'm working on a React codebase and we started having too much Routes, so i decided to refactor it a little bit. There is some logic to determine if we should redirect to a route that will check if you're authenticated, and if not will redirect you to the sign in page. We also have basic routes without that mechanism that just display a component ( for every page that doesnt need authentication like sign in, forgot password etc. )

I've decided to abstract that logic in a different component, that will ultimatley render a Route. As a first step in that direction, i decided to wrap the rendering of every route in a single component, instead of having the whole logic just laying down there.

Here's the code for the routes:

```
      <Switch>
        {Object.values(userRoutes).map((route: SanitizedRoute) => (
          <RouteController route={route} key={route.PATH} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
```

*RouterController.tsx*

```
  return (
    <Route
      path={props.route.PATH}
      exact={props.route.EXACT}
      render={() => {
        return <Layout>{props.route.COMPONENT}</Layout>;
      }}
    />
  );
```

All the information for the Route component is passed down as a prop. This is where i start getting problems. If i try to access `/path_b` what is rendered is the first element of my `userRoute` array, eventhough the Route doesn't match; /path_b or /path_c or /path_whatever will always render the compononent defined for /path_a.
Accessing any path actually returns the /path_a component as if it was the only one present in my Switch component.

If i were to replace the `RouteController` component by its content as such :

```
<Switch>
    {Object.values(userRoutes).map((route: SanitizedRoute) => (
          <Route
            path={route.PATH}
            exact={route.EXACT}
            key={route.PATH}
            render={() => {
              return <Layout>{route.COMPONENT}</Layout>;
            }}
          />
        ))}
</Switch>
```

Then everything would work fine as expected. Wrapping my `RouteController` with a `Switch` component is also working fine - although im not sure about the side effect of having a Switch per route ?

```
      {Object.values(userRoutes).map((route: SanitizedRoute) => (
        <Switch key={route.PATH}>
          <RouteController route={route} />
        </Switch>
      ))}
```

My questions are:

- Why isn't it possible to wrap all of those routes in a single  ?
- Is there some props from the  component i should manually pass down to the  component via my  ?
- I know that the  is used to render the first route that match the path. Does having multiple  kind of defeat the purpose of using a  in the first place ?

Here's a Sandbox to display this behavior : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-switch-test-forked-sqc98
I wrapper 1 route in a  component. When using the wrapper nothing work. If i copy paste the wrapper content inside the Switch, it does.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't it possible to wrap all of those routes in a single
> `<Switch>`?

This is because of how the `Switch` component works, it renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

[Switch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

The `RouteController` component is neither, so it's not involved in matching, and in fact only first component will be rendered. This is why you see only the first route rendered regardless of path.

> Is there some props from the `<Switch>` component I should manually
> pass down to the `<Route>` component via my `<RouterController>`?

It's possible to move/define a `path` prop (*and any other "route" prop*) on the `RouteController` the `Switch` may use for path matching, but this is ill-advised and not a documented use case of the `Switch` and `Route` components.

> I know that the `<Switch>` is used to render the first route that
> match the path. Does having multiple `<Switch>` kind of defeat the
> purpose of using a `<Switch>` in the first place?

Yes, if you are rendering multiple `Switch` components, each with only a single `Route` component then they aren't really switching routes at this point and you're relying on the inclusive route matching of any wrapping router, or exclusively matching in the case of any other wrapping switches.

## Solution

Instead of trying to map routes into your `RouterController` component and dealing with the issues of what is directly composing what, have your `RouterController` consume *all* the routes as a prop, and render them into a single `Switch` component.

RouterController.tsx

```
const RouterController = ({ routes }) => {
  // any component business logic

  return (
    <Switch>
      {routes.map((route: SanitizedRoute) => (
        <Route
          path={route.PATH}
          exact={route.EXACT}
          key={route.PATH}
          render={() => <Layout>{route.COMPONENT}</Layout>}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

...

```
<RouterController routes={Object.values(userRoutes)} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation and proposing a solution that seems to be, instinctively, the right way.
Your input sir, is priceless !

Comment: What would you recommend if i had different logic based on a route ? My goal was to have a component for the public routes, with its own rendering logic, and the private routes in another component, with also its own rendering logic ( with a redirect to the sign in page if the user is trying to access a private endpoint without being authenticated for example ).
Right now, since i have to loop through all routes, im starting to get nested conditions that im not very fond of.

Comment: @JorelAmthor You could implement a `PrivateRoute` component and incorporate that into the single configuration. You might also be able to use two separate configs, public and private, and use two `RouterControllers`. Either way you'll probably want/need a `PrivateRoute` component to handle authentications and redirects.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to include a PrivateRoute component into the Switch of the RouterController above, but i have the same issue as in my original question. Whenever i include a component, eventhough it returns a Route component, inside a Switch, it doesn't work since its not a Route child. I was trying to achieve something like this <Switch><PrivateRoute/><PublicRoute/></Switch> so each component would have its own logic.

Comment: @JorelAmthor A `PrivateRoute` component should certainly work with a `Switch`. Since this is a bit off-topic for the question you've posted here it would likely be more beneficial to you to post a new question on SO specifically regarding adding a `PrivateRoute` component to your configuration. If you do so then please feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: I'll open up a different question, thanks for proposing yourself. I feel like it should work too, but you can see in the problem depicted in my post, that if i wrap some route logic in a component, and render that component it a Switch, it doesnt work. If i copy paste my component logic direclty inside the Switch, however it is fine. I'll try to have a codepen demo or something similar.

Comment: @JorelAmthor Actually, I think I see what you are asking. If you add an `isPrivate` flag to your config (*or similar*) then it's as trivial as checking the flag and setting the wrapper component, i.e. something like `const Wrapper = route.isPrivate ? PrivateRoute : Route;` and `return <Wrapper .... the props .... />`. Make sense?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. But once again, lets say for a non private route, i will ultimately have a <Switch><Wrapper><Route/><Route/> etc.. </Wrapper></Switch> kind of structure right ? Well, if its not <Switch><Route/><Route/><Route/> etc..</Switch>, i will have the problem in my post. I feel like i have to pass some switch props down the line to the route for the Switch magic to happen but im unsure how.

Comment: @JorelAmthor I suppose that depends on how you implement your private route component, but generally it should be returning either a `Route` component or a `Redirect`. Perhaps you should just go ahead and post a new question or running codesandbox with what you are trying to do.

Comment: i added a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-switch-test-forked-sqc98 displaying the behavior i was talking about. Ive updated my post with the sandbox and will keep this post active, since ultimately my issue is still there, as to avoid unnecessary duplicatas.

Comment: @JorelAmthor Your `Wrapper` component isn't taking any route props, so it won't/can't participate in any route matching, and as such, is returned by the `Switch` by default since it's the first element child. I thought you were struggling with conditionally using a wrapping route component so you could apply some authentication checks. Consider this [codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-switch-test-forked-523qc?file=/src/App.js) from yours with a proper `Wrapper` route component.